# user.is_authenticated only working on home page

Tags: django, django-templates

I am thinking django only checks if the user is authenticated on the index page. In my base.html I have:

```
<li>{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}<a href="/users/logout/">Logout</a>{% else %}<a href="/users/login"></a>{% endif %}</li>
```

It works fine on my landing page, but when I navigate to any other page, logout nor login shows on the page.

Comment: Are you using `RequestContext` - or the `render` shortcut - to render the templates on those other pages?

Comment: Home page I am using `render` and on all other pages I've used `render_to_response`

Comment: Well, that is your answer. Use `render` throughout.

Comment: Thanks, using `return render(request, ...)` instead of `return render_to_response(...)` worked for me.